# Apache CXF wsdl2java client - string in CDATA instead of escape characters

Tags: escaping, cxf, special-characters, cdata, wsdl2java

I have ganerated webservice client using Apache CXF wsdl2java tool. It work fine, but in one method I have to send string that contain special characters. Generated client use escape characters. I do not want that. I want to place the string inside "<[!CDATA[ ]]>" block. I can add "<[!CDATA[ ]]>" manually in the code - that wont be a problem, but I have no idea how turn off cachracter escaping. Have anyone problem like that? How to fix it in the simplest way?

[Edit]: After Daniel Kulp answer I did this:

I have written interceptor:

```
public class CDATAInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public CDATAInterceptor(String phase) {
        super(phase);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        XMLStreamWriter writer = (XMLStreamWriter) message.getContent(XMLStreamWriter.class);
        if (writer != null && !(writer instanceof MyXmlWriter)) {
            message.setContent(XMLStreamWriter.class, new MyXmlWriter(writer));
        }
    }
}
```

I have added it to any possible phase (just in case - i probably should put in in MARSHAL or PRE_MARSHAL). Here is code how i add interceptors:

```
MyService service = new MyService(new URL(http://my_url_adress?wsdl));
proxy = service.getMyServiceSoap12();
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(proxy);

client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CDATAInterceptor(Phase.INVOKE));
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CDATAInterceptor(Phase.MARSHAL));
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CDATAInterceptor(Phase.MARSHAL_ENDING));
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CDATAInterceptor(Phase.POST_INVOKE));
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CDATAInterceptor(Phase.POST_LOGICAL));
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CDATAInterceptor(Phase.POST_LOGICAL_ENDING));
...
```

Here is MyXmlWriter class code:

```
public class MyXmlWriter implements XMLStreamWriter {

    protected XMLStreamWriter originalXmlWriter;

    public MyXmlWriter(XMLStreamWriter originalXmlWriter) {
        this.originalXmlWriter = originalXmlWriter;
    }

    public void writeStartElement(String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeStartElement(localName);
    }

    public void writeStartElement(String namespaceURI, String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeStartElement(namespaceURI, localName);
    }

    public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeStartElement(prefix, localName, namespaceURI);
    }

    public void writeEmptyElement(String namespaceURI, String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeEmptyElement(namespaceURI, localName);
    }

    public void writeEmptyElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeEmptyElement(prefix, localName, namespaceURI);
    }

    public void writeEmptyElement(String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeEmptyElement(localName);
    }

    public void writeEndElement() throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeEndElement();
    }

    public void writeEndDocument() throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
    }

    public void close() throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.close();
    }

    public void flush() throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.flush();
    }

    public void writeAttribute(String localName, String value) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeAttribute(localName, value);
    }

    public void writeAttribute(String prefix, String namespaceURI, String localName, String value) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeAttribute(prefix, namespaceURI, localName, value);
    }

    public void writeAttribute(String namespaceURI, String localName, String value) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeAttribute(namespaceURI, localName, value);
    }

    public void writeNamespace(String prefix, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeNamespace(prefix, namespaceURI);
    }

    public void writeDefaultNamespace(String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeDefaultNamespace(namespaceURI);
    }

    public void writeComment(String data) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeComment(data);
    }

    public void writeProcessingInstruction(String target) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeProcessingInstruction(target);
    }

    public void writeProcessingInstruction(String target, String data) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeProcessingInstruction(target, data);
    }

    public void writeCData(String data) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeCData(data);
    }

    public void writeDTD(String dtd) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeDTD(dtd);
    }

    public void writeEntityRef(String name) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeEntityRef(name);
    }

    public void writeStartDocument() throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
    }

    public void writeStartDocument(String version) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeStartDocument(version);
    }

    public void writeStartDocument(String encoding, String version) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeStartDocument(encoding, version);
    }

    public void writeCharacters(String text) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeCData(text);
    }

    public void writeCharacters(char[] text, int start, int len) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.writeCData(String.copyValueOf(text, len, len));
    }

    public String getPrefix(String uri) throws XMLStreamException {
        return this.originalXmlWriter.getPrefix(uri);
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix, String uri) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.setPrefix(prefix, uri);
    }

    public void setDefaultNamespace(String uri) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.setDefaultNamespace(uri);
    }

    public void setNamespaceContext(NamespaceContext context) throws XMLStreamException {
        this.originalXmlWriter.setNamespaceContext(context);
    }

    public NamespaceContext getNamespaceContext() {
        return this.originalXmlWriter.getNamespaceContext();
    }

    public Object getProperty(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return this.originalXmlWriter.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

This do not work. I have been debuging to check how it works and I notice that MyXmlWriter.writeCharacters(...) method in almost never used. Output message still have escape characters instead of being inside CDATA.

[Edit2]: 
I just found that I have to add line:

```
message.put("disable.outputstream.optimization", Boolean.TRUE);
```

source: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-jaxb-send-string-as-CData-td5524523.html

Comment: thank you so much. you saved my Sunday afternoon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ONLY way is to write an interceptor that would grab the XMLStreamWriter from the message, wrapper it with a new XMLStreamWriter that would override the characters method and call the delegate cdata method instead of characters.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I have edited question above by adding details about interceptor that I have written.

Comment: I have just open a bounty, and 2 min later I have found solution here: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-jaxb-send-string-as-CData-td5524523.html